# Javascript within AJAX loaded pages

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a main (index) page which loads pages dynamically and places them inside it's div but the Javascript within those pages doesn't execute. Specifically this part

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#regForm').submit(function(e) {
            register();
            e.preventDefault(); 
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Paste code where your load html via ajax

Comment: Dynamic loaded content does not execute inline script tags, see Sarfraz answer for a solution.

Comment: please show the full code of your javascript and ajax so i can edit it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use [`getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) like this:

```
$('#foo').load('bar.html', function(){
    $.getScript("js/fileName.js");
    // call a function from fileName.js
});
```

You will have to put your JS code in that file and call that via `getScript` and then you can call functions from it as shown above.

Answer (score 2):

Write your javascript in the index.php or write at the bottom of loaded page without document.ready

Answer (score 1):

This is in reality a cross-browser issue: When `<div>`s are dynamically filled with HTML containing `<script>` tags, these scripts may or may not run - and this behaviour is different not only between browsers, but also between browser versions.

The only workaround I know of is to extract your JS, send it seperately and execute it after the `<div>` content has been set.